# How to make a small letter large after a dash in pandas records?

Tags: python, pandas

I have entries in pandas, I need to change the small letter to a large letter after the dash sign. And it is best to record this change in a separate column.

Example dataframe:

```
data        columns_1

2020-05-20  test-word
```

Need result:

```
data        columns_1    columns_2

2020-05-20  test-word    Test-Word
```

I figured out that it is possible to change the first letter using:

```
df['columns_2'] = df['columns_1'].apply(lambda x: x.capitalize())
```

Is it possible to add something to this entry or is there some other method to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [`str.title`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.title.html):

```
df['columns_2'] = df['columns_1'].str.title()
```

output:

```
         data  columns_1   column-2
0  2020-05-20  test-word  Test-Word
```

Note that to capitalize after a dash (which is, I believe, not what you really want), you can use a regex:

```
df['after-dash'] = df['columns_1'].str.replace('-([a-z])',
                                               lambda m: m.group().upper(),
                                               regex=True)
```

output:

```
         data  columns_1 after-dash
0  2020-05-20  test-word  test-Word
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on from what you already have, creating a list and joining the words in the list will give the desired result:

```
df['columns_2'] = df['columns_1'].apply(lambda x: "-".join([p.capitalize() for p in x.split("-")]))
```